# nexus 4 not allowing me to copy files

Tags: nexus-4, windows, 4.3-jelly-bean, usb-debugging

I have a nexus 4 and had been trying to copy files with Windows 7 - but when I plug it in, it  doesn't show up in my device manager but when i enable USB debugging in the developer options, it shows up under "Other devices" and Windows can not seem to find the appropriate drivers for it. What's happening here? How can I make the phone to show up in my My Computer to copy files to/from it?

Thanks,
Ron

**edit** I now tried to install the drivers I found on http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1992345 and now my nexus 4 shows up as an Android ADB Interface but I still can't see it in my device manager... :o

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out, had to enable MTP mode under Settings => Storage - > settings button on top right -> USB computer connection and then enable MTP from there.